# JAXB: No XML element decl in the XML registry matching the namespace and name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

**Some code in the rootelement class:**

```
    @XmlElementRefs({
      @XmlElementRef(name = "footnoteLink", 
                     namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase", 
                     type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
```

It appears following description

```
No XML element decl in the XML registry matching the namespace 
'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase' and name 'footnoteLink'.
```

The reason is, that the ObjectFactory from this rootelement class has no decl found.

**But I found the footnoteLink in another object factory (xlink object factory) .**

```
private final static QName _FootnoteLink_QNAME 
                   = new QName("http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase", "footnoteLink");
```

**The point is the xlink declaration:**

```
   <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element ref="link:schemaRef" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <element ref="xbrli:unit"/>
          <element ref="link:footnoteLink"/>
        </choice>
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
```

I need to point the `@xmlElementRef "footnoteLink"` to the link object factory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

so I found a solution:

in my schema, it is set:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

and i need to add additional:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

but why????

Comment: too early, it isn't the reason... :(